# Is it possible to print client IP or MAC address from Arduino WiFi web server?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, tcpip

For a school project I want to make a little project with the Arduino Uno. I want to make a project that does something when a client connects to the WiFi shield.

My first thought was to print out the IP address or MAC address of the client but I can't find the codes for it. It is possible for me to print out the host IP? I have searched on the web for some time but only the ethernet shield will appear. Is my question even possible with an WiFi shield or do I have to get an ethernet shield?

Kind regards.

Comment: Which WiFi shield? There's two different official ones, plus a handful of third party ones.

Comment: It looks like Arduino only thought to provide access to that kind of information for UDP packets. They couldn't be bothered to do it for TCP connections. How **** is that?

Answer (score 1):

***** Assuming it is an ESP8266 based WI-FI shield: *****

Wifi shield > PC

Open serial monitor. Baud rate 155200. Also check COM ports.

Test AT commands by typing AT.

If it responds OK, you're good.

Type AT+CIFSR for IP adress.

Full list of AT commands in this link:

http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-doc/ESP8266ATCommandsSet.pdf

Comment: You're assuming an ESP8266 based WiFi shield. If it's an official Arduino WiFi shield of either version then it most certainly won't be that.

Comment: I edited to have a disclaimer in the anwser. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it local address anyways? Question looks like he wanted the IP of the other side. But I'm not sure if he's using AP mode and he wants assigned IP for the client or he wants connected TCP socket client IP.